# javafx textarea background color not css

Tags: javafx, textarea, scenebuilder

I want to change the background color of the textarea in SceneBuilder.

I failed to change in the style menu :-fx-background-color.

So I found to change the background color by using the CSS file.

```
.text-area .content{
  -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

But I want to change the other way except for the css file.
Please give me a hint .

Comment: CSS is the recommended approach. Why do you not want to use it?

Comment: @James_D Currently , in my project , i will need to change to code . Is there a way ?

Answer (score 6):

You can change it in Java code:

```
@Override
public void start( Stage stage )
{
    TextArea area = new TextArea();
    Scene scene = new Scene( area, 800, 600 );
    stage.setScene( scene );
    stage.show();

    Region region = ( Region ) area.lookup( ".content" );
    region.setBackground( new Background( new BackgroundFill( Color.BROWN, CornerRadii.EMPTY, Insets.EMPTY ) ) );

    // Or you can set it by setStyle()
    region.setStyle( "-fx-background-color: yellow" );
}
```

To do that we first lookup the child `Region` sub structure of text area then apply styling on it. This action should be done after the stage has been shown.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to use the setstyle of the textarea?

Answer (score 1):

I just found the solution to change the color of the background of TextArea in JavaFX. Write this in your controller class:

```
textarea.setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background:#000000;");
```

I was deep searching on the stackoverflow and eventually found it. The link is given below: [Textarea javaFx Color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36423200/textarea-javafx-color)

Happy coding!