# Textarea javaFx Color

Tags: java, javafx, textarea

I'm trying to develop an app that looks like a terminal console, am using a TextArea for that and my wish is to habe a black background and green text,

The point I want to do this without using any ccs template

I know that my question can look like a duplicated in here:

[javafx textarea background color not css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29745413/javafx-textarea-background-color-not-css)

or

[JavaFX CSS styling of TextArea does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21493634/javafx-css-styling-of-textarea-does-not-work)

but after reading those and trying what they suggested I found no luck to solve my issue

**What I tried so far (Unsuccessfully):**

in the FXML:

```
<TextArea 
    fx:id="terminalTextArea"
    layoutX="14.0"
    layoutY="85.0"
    prefHeight="64.0"
    prefWidth="402.0"
    style="-fx-font-family: Consolas; -fx-highlight-fill: #00ff00; -fx-highlight-text-fill: #000000; -fx-text-fill: #00ff00; -fx-background-color:#000000;"
    text="Terminal"
    AnchorPane.leftAnchor="10.0"
    AnchorPane.rightAnchor="10.0">
    <font>
        <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
    </font>
</TextArea>
```

and in the source-code:

```
@Override
public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
    System.out.println("init here");
    terminalTextArea.setStyle("-fx-text-fill: black;");
}
```

The only thing that I get is a bordered color like in the image below:

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to do this without CSS? That is the supported mechanism for changing the style of a control.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The recommended way is to use an external CSS file, as in the examples you linked.

If for some reason you don't want to do that, try

```
style="-fx-control-inner-background:#000000; -fx-font-family: Consolas; -fx-highlight-fill: #00ff00; -fx-highlight-text-fill: #000000; -fx-text-fill: #00ff00; "
```

in your FXML file, or equivalently

```
terminalTextArea.setStyle("-fx-control-inner-background:#000000; -fx-font-family: Consolas; -fx-highlight-fill: #00ff00; -fx-highlight-text-fill: #000000; -fx-text-fill: #00ff00; ");
```

in your controller's `initialize()` method.

SSCCE:

StyledTextArea.fxml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.TextArea?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.Font?>

<HBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" >
    <padding>
        <Insets top="12" left="12" right="12" bottom="12"/>
    </padding>
    <TextArea 
        prefHeight="64.0"
        prefWidth="402.0"
        style="-fx-control-inner-background:#000000; -fx-font-family: Consolas; -fx-highlight-fill: #00ff00; -fx-highlight-text-fill: #000000; -fx-text-fill: #00ff00; "
        text="Terminal">

        <font>
            <Font name="System Bold" size="14.0" />
        </font>
    </TextArea>
</HBox>
```

and a test class:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class StyledTextArea extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(
            FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("StyledTextArea.fxml"))
        ));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: `-fx-control-inner-background: #000000` sets the background color of the text area, just FYI for other people that may have tried `-fx-background-color`

Answer (score 0):

It's simple, just put an id name inside the elment you want like:

```
AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" prefHeight="180.0" prefWidth="430.0"
```

or in Scene Builder in properties just down below the title JavaFX CSS write the name and style this element in your CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to set the background of textArea using CSS, you should have this attributes of CSS .content . viewport `//additional .scroll-pane`

Codes:

```
#tContent{
    -fx-pref-width: 180;
    -fx-pref-height: 110;

}
.content {
    -fx-background-color: transparent;
}
.viewport{
    -fx-background-color: transparent; 
}
```